# Setting Up Emails in Code Igniter 2.02

Tags: codeigniter, php

I’m getting a lot of errors. And I've tried several suggestion across different sites, deleted the parent function, removed the array, updated my php ini file, no luck.
This is the first of 13 errors I’m getting.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport “ssl” – did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1673

Someone please help.

```
class Email extends CI_Controller
{
function index()
{
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypassword';

    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'My Name');
    $this->email->to('myemail@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('This is an email test');
    $this->email->message('Its working. Great!');

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo 'Your email was sent, dude.';
    }

    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: did you check if your system has openssl library installed to enable scripts to make ssl connections from your machine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a phpinfo(); statement in a .php file to check if the openssl extension actually loaded.

In your `php.ini` enable **php_openssl**

```
extension=php_openssl.so
```

if you are on Windows, then

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I recall, I've enabled that already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, if you're using Wampserver in Windows, you can go to the taskbar, click the wampserver icon, then PHP -> PHP extensions and select php_openssl.

Answer (score 0):

Mayowa:

Perhaps I'm a little late and you already has this solved.

After searching a lot in the web I found out that for mail configuration simple quotes and double quotes is not the same.

I use the /application/config/email.php file and after many attempts I found out that this will not work:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypassword';
```

But this will:

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = "myemail@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "mypassword";
```

Hope it helps.